# Symfony 2 anon access with security context

Tags: security, symfony, authentication, authorization

I am working on a project where a url under the path /video/ should be available both anonymously and logged in. If the user is logged in they should see some additional elements, a form for example. However, if i allow anonymous access i get no security context and cannot check if user is authenticated to show the extra elements.

This are the two configuration variants i have tried:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/user/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: _security_check
            login_path: /user/login

        logout:
            path:   _user_logout
            target: _user_login

        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    - { path: ^/video/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

However in that case you need to log in, in the other case i cannot get security context to check if user is logged in:

```
    firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/user/login$
        security: false

    video:
        pattern: ^/video/
        anonymous: ~

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: _security_check
            login_path: /user/login

        logout:
            path:   _user_logout
            target: _user_login

        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    - { path: ^/video/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

How do i go about to achieve this simple thing?

Comment: you could check with app.user

Answer (score 0):

The second solution is almost correct.just share the context of 'video' and 'secured_area' firewall.that is give them the same context value i.e:

```
video:
     path: ^/video/
     anonymous: ~
     context: foobar #this is the line in question
secured_area:
     ....#same as what you wrote
     context: foobar
```

this way if you're logged in, in `secured_area` the session will be accessible in `video` firewall.also there is need to login if the user is trying to access ^/video/ anonymously